# In a Visual Studio 2010 C/C++, what does the "Rescan Solution" operation do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying to compile a third-party project and I'm getting a few linking issues.  I'm not having much trouble fixing the minor issues but I noticed their was a "Rescan Solution" option in the context menu of the project or solution.

I clicked it but it didn't seem to do anything.  What, exactly, does it do?

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't just google this. Googling for 'Rescan Solution' could've already told you "all out of date files will be checked and the database updated"

Comment: I did.  You must have received different results because most of them deal with databases.  I even tried the search '"rescan solution" site:msdn.microsoft.com' which I had hoped would take me to an official MSDN documentation page.  It didn't, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: @Mike: I'm glad that tells you something, because it's absolutely meaningless to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command updates out-of-date files in the project browsing database. Nothing to do with compilation/linking problems.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That's what I had suspected but I wanted to be sure.