# Getting errors E1696 with all headers in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was trying to make a window with GLFW, GLEW and OpenGL but once I wanted to upload to GitHub one file called "Browse.VC.db" was too big. So I deleted it (I know now that this was stupid idea :) ). And after deleting, VS shows buch of errors of number E1696 like:

```
E1696 cannot open source file "GL/glu.h"
E1696 cannot open source file "stddef.h"
E1696 cannot open source file "stdint.h"
E1696 cannot open source file "iostream"
E1696 cannot open source file "string"
```

and many many more.
Also I am getting errors E0020 identifier "unint64_t" is undefined and E0135 namespace "std" has no member "string" but I think that is because of E1696 errors.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. I am using Version 10.0.17763.0 of Windows SDK and I am not using precompiled headers.

I tried changing Windows SDK version to 8.1 but I does not work. I checked if I installed Windows Universal C Runtime SDK but it does not work too.

I found lot of tutorials but they were about problems with projects upgraded from older VS to newer one.

This is how I am including headers in .h filed:

```
#pragma once
#include <IO/Log.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

Comment: Try Project/Rescan Solution. If that doesn't work just delete everything except the code and recreate the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You deleted Visual Studio's "cache" of things used by your project.

Go to *Project* and hit [*Rescan Solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259010/560648) to recreate it.

Next time, don't just randomly delete files without the slightest idea what they are; if you want to exclude something in your project folder from version control, add its path to your `.gitignore` file (or just don't commit it).

Comment: Thanks fot answer. I rebuild solution and it works. But do you know what can project miss after deleting cache file? Some settings?

Comment: @PeterVeris It's the cache for Intellisense. No point going into intricate detail but you removed Intellisense's memory of where everything is, so now it can't find anything and thinks everything's undeclared.